# Decimal to Binary conversion using recursion with while loop

Tags: c, binary

my binary conversion doesn't work after it recurs a second time, it seems to work only during the first time through.  The purpose of the is have a user input a number to convert to Hex, Octal, and brinary from a integer and keep on asking and converting until the user inputs 0.  Please help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long toBinary(int);

int main(void) {
    int number = 0;
    long bnum;   
    int zero = 0;

    while(number != zero) {
        puts("\nPlease enter a number you would like to convert to");
        puts("\nHexadecimal, octal, and binary: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if(number != zero) {
            printf("\nThe Hexadecimal format is: %x", number);
            printf("\nThe Octal format is: %o", number);
            bnum = toBinary(number);
            printf("\nThe binary format is: %ld\n", bnum);
        }
        else {
            puts("\nI'm sorry you have to enter a number greater than 0.\n");
            puts("\nOr have enter an invalid entry.");

        }
    }
    return 0;
}   

long toBinary(int number) {
    static long bnum, remainder, factor = 1;
    int long two = 2;
    int ten = 10;

    if(number != 0) {
        remainder = number % two;
        bnum = bnum + remainder * factor;
        factor = factor * ten;
        toBinary(number / 2);
    }
    return bnum;
}
```

Comment: Why have `int zero = 0` is going to be a mystery to all of us? You do know that computers are binary machines in the first place. There is no conversion just a different representation

Comment: Curious to know how `32` `0's` or `1's` can be represented in a `long`

Comment: I'm new to c programming i just started using c like 2 weeks ago so i'm really fresh to this so i'm not sure.

Comment: So are you saying should change long to something else like a unsigned int or just int?

Comment: In case of binary it is better to use array of characters. see the answer posted below

Comment: `doesn't work after it recurs a second time` It is necessary to reset the static variable.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a function to convert an integer to its binary representation.

Assuming the `int` is 32 bits then this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[33];
    str[32] = 0;
    int x = 13, loop;
    for (loop = 31; loop >= 0; --loop) {
       str[loop]  = (x & 1) ? '1' : '0';
       x = x >> 1;
    }
    printf("As %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

You can make this into a function, read x etc...

**EDIT**

For octal/hex - `printf` will do this for you

**EDIT**

Here goes recursively

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintBinary(int n, int x) {
   if (n > 0) {
      PrintBinary(n - 1, x >> 1);
   }
   printf("%c",(x & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main()
{
   PrintBinary(32,12);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `loop = 31`, 32 to 0 makes 33:)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying not to use an array, I'm trying to do it recursively.

Comment: ... Btw you are effectively using the calling stack as the array

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am surprised it even works once. Firstly, your while condition is while number does not equal zero. But right off the bat, number equals 0 and zero equals 0. Therefore the while should never run. If you want to keep this condition for the main loop, change it to a do-while loop: **do { //code } while (number != zero);**. This will run the code at least once, then check if the inputted number doesn't equal zero. That brings me to the next issue; your scanf for number is scanning for a double and placing it in a regular integer memory spot. Quick fix: **scanf("%i",&number);**. Also I am finding some functions called puts.. I find it best to keep with one printing function, printf. Now, I am finding afew errors in your toBinary function, but if it works than I guess it works. These are all the errors i could find, I hope this helped. But for future reference there is no need to declare a variable for a const number like 2 or 10 at this level.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, i set number to zero because i was trying to find the error with the second recursion, when i try to a second conversion by binary conversion comes out wrong

Comment: Your welcome. And about your binary conversion, you are going to need a loop. Inside the loop you should have a way to determine the size of number that hasn't been changed to binary and based on the size check if the remainder is 0 or not. i.e 
**`for (i=8;i!=-1;i--) {
    x = pow(2,i);
    if (number > x) {
        if (number%x==0)
            printf("0");
        else
            printf("1");
        number=-x;
    }
}`**

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>

char* toBinary(int32_t number, int index){
    static char bin[32+1] = {0}, *ret;
    if(index == 32){
        memset(bin, '0', 32);
        return toBinary(number, 31);
    } else if(number & (1<<index))
        bin[31-index] = '1';

    if(index)
        (void)toBinary(number, index-1);
    else
        for(ret = bin; *ret == '0';++ret);

    return ret;
}

...
int number = -1;
...
printf("\nThe binary format is: %s\n", toBinary(number, 32));
```